# Definition of ‘In a row’

Tags: definition, dictionaries

The following definition is what ‘in a row’ is defined as, in the Cambridge dictionary.

> In a row
>
> one after another without a break

What does ‘without a break’ modify?

Comment: Without a gap in the row (line).

Comment: @Kate Bunting Can the definition have two modifiers? ‘without a gap,’ and ‘in the row (line)?

Comment: If 'without a break' modifies anything, it's the description 'one after another'.  The _meaning_ is that objects are placed in a line without any gaps, or things happen one after another without a pause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dictionary definitions tend to be shortened expressions.

The phrase "without a break" modifies and clarifies the phrase "one after another"

Here some stars in a row

```
****************************************************************
```

They are one after another.  And they are without a gap